# Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression (vb.net)

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to make a form in which a user can create an account, but I am getting the following error:

Additional information: Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression '@Re-Enter Password'.

My code is as follows:

```
Private Sub connect()

    dbProvider = "PROVIDER=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" 'Sets the provider of the database

    dbSource = "Data Source= F:\CarphoneWarehouseDatabase.accdb" 'Sets the location of the database

    con.ConnectionString = dbProvider & dbSource 'tells the connection where to find the database and who provides it

    con.Open() 'Opens connection

End Sub

Private Sub SubmitBtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SubmitBtn.Click

    connect() 'Start connect procedure

    Dim sql As String

    sqlquery.Connection = con
    sqlquery.CommandText = sql

    'sql = "INSERT INTO PersonalDetails([Forename],[Surname]) VALUES('test1','test1')" 'Insert the two values into the database

    sqlquery.CommandText = "INSERT INTO PersonalDetails([Forename],[Surname],[Username],[Password],[Re-Enter Password],[Email Address],[Re-Enter Email Address],[Date of Birth]) values (@Forename, @Surname, @Username, @Password, @Re-Enter Password, @Email Address, @Re-Enter Email Address, @Date of Birth)"

    sqlquery.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Forename", ForenameTxtBox.Text)
    sqlquery.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Surname", SurnameTxtBox.Text)
    sqlquery.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", UsernameTxtBox.Text)
    sqlquery.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", PasswordTxtBox.Text)
    sqlquery.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Re-Enter Password", ReEnterPasswordTxtBox.Text)
    sqlquery.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email Address", EmailAddressTxtBox.Text)
    sqlquery.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Re-Enter Email Address", ReEnterEmailTxtBox.Text)
    sqlquery.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date of Birth", DateOfBirthTxtBox.Text)

    sqlquery.ExecuteNonQuery()

    MsgBox("Row(s) Inserted !! ") 'Displays message box informing the user that the database has been added to

    con.Close() 'Connection closed

End Sub
```

Comment: parameters are meant to be one word, not phrases.  why would you want to save the Re-Enters anyway?  They just validate that the first entry is correct.  Also, you should not save PWs as plaintext.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. What would you suggest I amend the code to then?

Answer (score 0):

Dash (-) is not allowed, you should not use spaces in @param names too

Comment: Tried both and now it says 'unknown field name'.

Comment: Have you ensured the CommandText and each of the AddWithValue do not have spaces and dashes?

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the dash and space in the name of parameter identifier.
For example rename @Re-Enter Password in @ReEnterPassword